# Overleaf Easy LongTable

Tags: overleaf, longtable

I'm trying to make a long table in overleaf to represent inclusion and exclusion criteria. I've used "longtblr" and set the parameters "colspec = {X[1.9]|X[6]|X[6]}, rowhead = 1, hlines,". I also tried the "landscape". But every time there're conflicts some rows don't compile (don't show) in the output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLPX.png)

Comment: ask to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question that show us what kind of problems yoy faced when using tabularray